# Observable collection item property changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a column class which uses view model base to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (lazy I know):

```
public class Column : ViewModelBase
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public bool Anonymize { get; set; }
}
```

And then a list of columns:

```
public class Columns : ObservableCollection<Column>
{
}
```

In my view model I have a property columns and I am binding that to a combo box with a checkbox and textblock:

```
private Columns _tableColumns;
public Columns TableColumns
{
  get
  {
    return _tableColumns;
  }
  set
  {
    _tableColumns = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("TableColumns");
  }
}
```

```
  <ComboBox Name="cbColumns" ItemsSource="{Binding TableColumns}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Anonymize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

When I change the Anonymize property through the checkbox on an item, how do make the Columns property change in the view model to reflect this?

Comment: Have you tried `TwoWay` binding mode?

Comment: What exactly is the "Columns property in the view model"? I can only see a `TableColumns` property of type `Columns`. Do you want to change that, or do you want to change the `Anonymize` property of the current `Column` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Column` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (which you say it does).  You also need to raise that event it when the value of `Anonymize` changes (which you don't).

Comment: +1 But then the question would have to be "when I change the Anonymize property (e.g. in code) how to make the view reflect this change?". It was asked the other way round, which i don't understand at all.

Comment: Hm, you're right - I may have missed the point entirely!  That said, if that's what the OP requires then I'm not sure why the markup as posted wouldn't work.  Confused!

Comment: Well - can't I tell it is a Friday. The question was so stupid even I don't know why I asked it, I have what I need now so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `Anonymize` property only from the UI, you are done. If you'd like to see the changes(from the backend) on the UI, you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `Column` class.

```
public class Column : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string columnName;
    public bool anonymize;

    public string ColumnName
    {
        get { return columnName; }
        set
        {
            columnName = value; RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ColumnName");
        }
    }
    public bool Anonymize
    {
        get { return anonymize; }
        set { anonymize = value; RaiseOnPropertyChanged("Anonymize"); }
    }

    public void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var eh = PropertyChanged;
        if (eh != null)
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what has been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Anonymize` state changes it will need to notify the view model that it needs to modify the collection of columns. The way I've solved this before is to add a CheckChanged event to the Column class that is raised when `Anonymize`. The the view model subscribes to  the event after it creates the Column object but it is added to the `Columns` collection. When CheckChanged is raised the view model adds/removes the item from the Columns collection.